# runningApplications returns terminated processes?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I've implemented a class which has to wait for a specific process to be finished (started by using `NSWorkspace openFile:withApplication`).

I've tried `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications]` and it does return an array of running processes. But it still contains the process I want to monitor even when this process isn't running anymore (it disappeared from the Activity Monitor and does not show up in `top` command).

Does anybody have a clue how I can monitor a process correctly? Checking the `terminated` property or the `processIdentifier` property does not do the trick (`terminated` is still `NO` and the `processIdentifier` contains a valid looking process id).

Comment: `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications]` returns running applications at the time you call it. I tested it this way : 1. I launched the Calculator app. 2. Called `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications]` 3. Quit Calculator app 4. Called runningApplications.

It worked perfectly : calculator app appears in step 2 but not in step 4. I am not sure how you are using it.

Comment: I've tried it with a do-while loop which contains nothing but a `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2]` and the check for the running process within the while statement.

Comment: Seems like exactly this sleep caused the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-runningApplications` is only updated if the main run loop is allowed to run. If you're polling or otherwise keeping the main run loop busy, then it'll never update.

From `NSWorkspace`:

> Similar to the NSRunningApplication class’s properties, this property will only change when the main run loop is run in a common mode. Instead of polling, use key-value observing to be notified of changes to this array property.
>
> It is safe to call this method from any of your app’s threads. The method returns its value atomically.
>
> This value returned by this method is observable using key-value observing.

I would probably just fetch the `NSRunningApplication` itself, and KVO observe its `terminated` property. Just make sure the main run loop is allowed to keep going.

If you have a GUI app, that's the normal state of affairs; just return from your method. If this is a commandline app, then the best solution in my experience working with `NSWorkspace` is to put `[NSApp run]` in `main()` to kick it off like a GUI app. That usually means creating a app delegate and putting most of your code in there rather than in `main()`. When you would normally exit from your program, just call `[NSApp terminate:nil]`.

Of course you can also just run the main runloop yourself by hand with `runMode:beforeDate:`. (I remember that it worked better for me to use an `NSApplication`, though. But I can't remember why. It may have been to listen to notifications. So maybe hand-running the run loop is fine.)

Comment: Looks like the `NSRunningApplication` object cannot be observed. The attached observer is never being triggered (I don't know why).

Comment: But your hint with `runMode:beforeDate:` did the trick. Thanks a lot!

Comment: And, of course, I'm trying to check if child processes have quit after running off the end of my run loop while cleaning up. Argh! Moral of the story is never write a main function on Apple.